# onclick method calling javascript where jquery used to display value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below shows a simplistic view of my issue.
The value displayed doesn't work until 07778, anything below as shown, manipulates the number for some reason.  Ever seen anything like this.  I wonder if its something with jquery?  using 1.7.1.min.js (yes i know its outdated, but i don't have the authority to update our site at this time.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function ShowText(empid) {
            $("#text").text("Valule Passed To Function: " + empid)
            return false;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text" class="text" style="margin-bottom:34px;"></div>

    <a onclick="ShowText(01133);return false;">01133</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(02133);return false;">02133</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(03133);return false;">03133</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(04133);return false;">04133</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(05133);return false;">05133</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(06133);return false;">06133</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07133);return false;">07133</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07500);return false;">07500</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07700);return false;">07700</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07750);return false;">07750</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07770);return false;">07770</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07777);return false;">07777</a>
    <br />
    <div style="border-bottom:solid 2px black; width:100%; text-align:center;">BROKEN :(</div>
    <div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">WORKING :)</div>
    <a onclick="ShowText(07778);return false;">07778</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07779);return false;">07779</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07780);return false;">07780</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07799);return false;">07799</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(07800);return false;">07800</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(08000);return false;">08000</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(08133);return false;">08133</a>
    <br />
    <a onclick="ShowText(09133);return false;">09133</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Update, i did take out the jquery and use Document.GetElementById("#text").innerHTML = empid; and it returns the same exact results!  i'm stumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's subtle, but you've come across an interesting quirk in the way JavaScript handles numbers.

```
ShowText(07778);
```

This works. So we'll ignore it. *[edit - see note below]*

```
ShowText(07700);
```

This doesn't; it actually gives a value of 4032. What you've missed is that **7700 in octal is 4032 in decimal**.

Thus, the reason why it isn't working is that JavaScript is treating your 0-prefixed numbers, that contain no digit above '7' as octal. Simply remove the leading zero (you're treating them as numeric anyway), or add quotes, and your code will work fine.

For a reference covering this behaviour, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt:

> Although discouraged by ECMAScript 3 and forbidden by ECMAScript 5, many implementations interpret a numeric string beginning with a leading 0 as octal.

*Note: We're ignoring it because it's not throwing the error. The* **reason***, as should now be apparent, is that 7778 is not a valid octal number, so the parser has decided that it wasn't actually octal at all and was just a normal integer with a leading zero.*

Comment: Ahhh i seee it! Thank you much

Comment: I guess the one question i have is why does it show octal values at 07777 but shows normal values at 07778?  maybe irrelevant, but i am curious if you do know :)

Comment: Because 7778 isn't a valid octal number (they can only be 0-7), so it reverted back to assuming it was a normal integer.

Comment: Yep, that makes perfect sense.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're accidentally using octal numbers, because you start your numbers with a leading zero. Drop the leading zero and you get the expected behaviour.

For example `01133` (base 8) is `603` (base 10). If you want to keep the leading zero, use strings instead.